# ASP.NET Core MVC Encrypt/Decrypt QueryString Values

Tags: c#, encryption, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC, C#, Entity Framework Core Code First and SQL Server 2016.

I created a web form and all of my CRUD operations are working fine. However, I need some help on Encrypting / Decrypting the Querystring values that get passed to the Confirmation, Edit and Delete Views.

On my Index page I would also like to Encrypt the EmployeeID when a user hovers over the Edit and Delete links to those Action Methods. I don't want them to be visible on the Index Page.

Please see my code that I have below.

**Models**

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }

    public int AppointmentID { get; set; }
    public Appointment Appointment { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Appointment
{
    public int AppointmentID { get; set; }
    public string TimeSlot { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public class WinTenDbContext : DbContext
{
    public WinTenDbContext(DbContextOptions<WinTenDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasKey(e => e.EmployeeID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .Property(e => e.FirstName)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .Property(e => e.LastName)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50)
            .IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .HasKey(d => d.DepartmentID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Department>()
            .Property(d => d.Name)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Appointment>()
            .HasKey(a => a.AppointmentID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Appointment>()
            .Property(a => a.TimeSlot)
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)")
            .HasMaxLength(50);
    }
}
```

**ViewModels**

```
public class EmployeeFormVM
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your First Name")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your Last Name")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select your Department")]
    [Display(Name = "Department")]
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select your Appointment")]
    [Display(Name = "Appointment")]
    public int AppointmentID { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
}
```

**EmployeesController**

```
public class EmployeesController : Controller
{
    private readonly WinTenDbContext _context;

    public EmployeesController(WinTenDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    //// GET: Employees
    //public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    //{
    //    var winTenDbContext = _context.Employees.Include(e => e.Appointment).Include(e => e.Department);
    //    return View(await winTenDbContext.ToListAsync());
    //}

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;
        ViewData["FirstNameSortParm"] = sortOrder == "fname" ? "fname_desc" : "fname";
        ViewData["LastNameSortParm"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "lname_desc" : "";
        ViewData["DeptNameSortParm"] = sortOrder == "deptname" ? "deptname_desc" : "deptname";
        ViewData["DateSortParm"] = sortOrder == "time_slot" ? "time_slot_desc" : "time_slot";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;

        var employees = from s in _context.Employees.Include(e => e.Appointment).Include(e => e.Department)
                        select s;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            employees = employees.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(searchString)
                                   || s.FirstName.Contains(searchString));
        }

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "fname":
                employees = employees.OrderBy(s => s.FirstName);
                break;
            case "fname_desc":
                employees = employees.OrderByDescending(s => s.FirstName);
                break;
            case "lname_desc":
                employees = employees.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
                break;
            case "deptname":
                employees = employees.OrderBy(s => s.Department.Name);
                break;
            case "deptname_desc":
                employees = employees.OrderByDescending(s => s.Department.Name);
                break;
            case "time_slot":
                employees = employees.OrderBy(s => s.Appointment.AppointmentID);
                break;
            case "time_slot_desc":
                employees = employees.OrderByDescending(s => s.Appointment.AppointmentID);
                break;
            default:
                employees = employees.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
                break;
        }

        int pageSize = 10;
        return View(await PaginatedList<Employee>.CreateAsync(employees.AsNoTracking(), page ?? 1, pageSize));
    }

    // GET: Employees/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var employee = await _context.Employees
            .Include(e => e.Appointment)
            .Include(e => e.Department)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EmployeeID == id);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(employee);
    }

    // GET: Employees/Confirmation/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Confirmation(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var employee = await _context.Employees.Include(d => d.Department).Include(a => a.Appointment)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EmployeeID == id);

        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(employee);
    }

    // GET: Employees/Create
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        var departments = _context.Departments.ToList();
        var appointments = _context.Appointments.Include(x => x.Employees).Where(x => !x.Em‌​ployees.Any()).ToLis‌​t();

        var viewModel = new EmployeeFormVM
        {
            Departments = departments,
            Appointments = appointments
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(EmployeeFormVM employee)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var emp = new Employee();
            {
                emp.FirstName = employee.FirstName;
                emp.LastName = employee.LastName;
                emp.DepartmentID = employee.DepartmentID;
                emp.AppointmentID = employee.AppointmentID;
            }

            // Query DB to check if Employee exists with same First/Last Name
            Employee existingEmployee = await _context.Employees.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.FirstName == employee.FirstName && m.LastName == employee.LastName);
            if (existingEmployee != null)
            {
                // Display Error if duplicate employee
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "An employee with this name has already registered. Please contact the Service Desk for any scheduling conflicts.");
                employee.Departments = _context.Departments.ToList();
                //employee.Appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();
                employee.Appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();
                return View(employee);
            }

            // Query DB to check if appointment has already been assigned to an employee
            Employee existingAppointment = await _context.Employees.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.AppointmentID == employee.AppointmentID);
            if (existingAppointment != null)
            {
                // Display error if the appointment was already chosen
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "This appointment has already been taken. Please select another timeslot.");
                employee.Departments = _context.Departments.ToList();
                //employee.Appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();
                employee.Appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();
                return View(employee);
            }

            _context.Add(emp);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            //return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

            var newlyCreatedId = emp.EmployeeID;
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Confirmation), new { id = newlyCreatedId });
        }
        return View(employee);
    }

    // GET: Employees/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var employeevm = new EmployeeFormVM();
        {
            Employee employee = await _context.Employees.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EmployeeID == id);

            if (employee == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            employeevm.EmployeeID = employee.EmployeeID;
            employeevm.FirstName = employee.FirstName;
            employeevm.LastName = employee.LastName;

            // Retrieve list of Departments
            var departments = _context.Departments.ToList();
            employeevm.Departments = departments;
            // Set the selected department
            employeevm.DepartmentID = employee.DepartmentID;

            // Retrieve list of Appointments
            var appointments = _context.Appointments.ToList();
            employeevm.Appointments = appointments;
            // Set the selected department
            employeevm.AppointmentID = employee.AppointmentID;
        }
        return View(employeevm);
    }

    // POST: Employees/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(EmployeeFormVM vmEdit)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Employee employee = _context.Employees.SingleOrDefault(e => e.EmployeeID == vmEdit.EmployeeID);

            if (employee == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            employee.FirstName = vmEdit.FirstName;
            employee.LastName = vmEdit.LastName;
            employee.DepartmentID = vmEdit.DepartmentID;
            employee.AppointmentID = vmEdit.AppointmentID;

            try
            {
                _context.Update(employee);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!EmployeeExists(vmEdit.EmployeeID))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(vmEdit);
    }

    // GET: Employees/Delete/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var employee = await _context.Employees
            .Include(e => e.Appointment)
            .Include(e => e.Department)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EmployeeID == id);
        if (employee == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(employee);
    }

    // POST: Employees/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        var employee = await _context.Employees.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EmployeeID == id);
        _context.Employees.Remove(employee);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    private bool EmployeeExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Employees.Any(e => e.EmployeeID == id);
    }
}
```

**Create View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Employees"))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "validation-summary-errors" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(e => e.FirstName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(e => e.LastName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.DepartmentID)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(d => d.DepartmentID, new SelectList(Model.Departments, "DepartmentID", "Name"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.DepartmentID)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(a => a.AppointmentID)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.AppointmentID, new SelectList(Model.Appointments, "AppointmentID", "TimeSlot"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.AppointmentID)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    }
```

**Edit View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Employees"))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(e => e.FirstName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(e => e.LastName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.LastName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(d => d.DepartmentID)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(d => d.DepartmentID, new SelectList(Model.Departments, "DepartmentID", "Name"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.DepartmentID)
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(a => a.AppointmentID)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.AppointmentID, new SelectList(Model.Appointments, "AppointmentID", "TimeSlot"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.AppointmentID)
        </div>

        @Html.HiddenFor(e => e.EmployeeID)

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    }
```

**Confirmation View**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <img src="~/images/confirm.png" />
    <h2>Thank you @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName) @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)!</h2>    
    <p>Your <b>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Appointment.TimeSlot)</b> appointment has been booked. If you need to reschedule this appointment, please call the Service Desk at x1380.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at IDataProtectionProvider.

Comment: @Max, Thank you for replying. However, I looked at the docs.asp.net site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction and it states **Windows provides DPAPI for desktop applications but this is unsuitable for web applications.** on the first line. Is there any other way to encrypt/decrypt querystring values.

Comment: Hi @BrianBrian Check this link you will find detail implementation https://tutexchange.com/encrypting-and-decrypting-query-string-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Max is right. `IDataProtectionProvider` is what you want to look at.

`IDataProtectionProvider` can be used on windows or unix.

It's true it can't be used as a clientside javascript library but there are ways to still leverage it.

The simplest approach is to encrypt the ID before sending the view's HTML to the browser and including the encrypted ID in an HTML data- attribute, etc, where your client javascript can get access to it to post back (or used in a query string if you so choose) with the edit or delete request.

Below is an example of how to use the `IDataProtectionProvider` in a controller to encrypt and decrypt an id.

```
 public class HomeController : Controller{
     IDataProtector dataProtector;
    
     public HomeController(IDataProtectionProvider provider){
         dataProtector = provider.CreateProtector(GetType().FullName);
     }
    
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() {
        int id = 1234;

        string encryptedId = dataProtector.Protect(id.ToString());

        int decryptedId = 0;
        if(int.TryParse(dataProtector.Unprotect(encryptedId), out decryptedId) == false){
            throw new Exception("Invalid cypher text");
        }

        //at this point decryptedId contains the decrypted value.

   }
```

Please note that when this dataProtector is created above it uses `GetType().FullName` as the encryption "purpose".  This is a common practice that appears in the .net core framework code.  The "purpose" is used as additional context data when doing the encryption and is essentially used to derive a purpose specific subkey for encrypting/decrypting data.  In this case since I set it to `GetType().FullName` it will be the fully qualified name of the controller.  That's great if you are encrypting and decrypting from within the same controller, it will work no problem.  *BUT*, if you want to encrypt in one controller and decrypt in a different controller (or any other class for that matter), then the important thing to know is that the purpose string passed in this line `dataProtector = provider.CreateProtector(purpose);` MUST be the same for the dataProtector used to decrypt as it was for the dataProtector used to encrypt.  (i.e. it can't be the class name if the class used to decrypt is different than the one used to encrypt).

Additionally, this is a article that you may find useful: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/295/encryption-and-decryption-in-asp-net-core

Comment: I'm not sure why I would want to hide the real id's... it should not make any difference as long as your server-side code works correctly and checks all neccessary persmissions before a user can do anything.

Comment: @Robert I totally agree that that the downstream code needs to do all necessary permission checks before the user should be allowed to do anything.  However, security is often best handled via a layered approach so that if any one security layer fails there are other security layers that still prevent unwanted actions.  Working with encrypted id's in the client can serve to add an additional security layer, but as you said, ultimately checking permissions is very important. (Also I was just trying to answer the question the poster asked).

Comment: You're right, Ron. I should have commented the OP, btw.

Comment: @Robert, I was trying to use this approach https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/295/encryption-and-decryption-in-asp-net-core but this articles doesn't seem to work with ASP.NET Core 2.0. So, I went to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection but it doesn't show how to implement either for use with QueryStrings. Can someone please show me how to implement with the code I have above?

Comment: @RonC, Yes, this will be used as a second layer of security. Just having trouble implementing it.

Comment: @BrianBrian I've added example code for how to implement encrypting and decryption of an id in a controller.

Comment: @RonC, I'm sorry, I must have missed that prior to my comment. However, after looking at what you supplied, I'm still confused as to how to implement that with the code I have. Not, trying to be a pain, just confused. The article that I initially looked which is the same as you provided seems to be using a different method than what I have for retrieving the data in the query.

Comment: @BrianBrian You primary question, as I understood it, was how to encrypt and decrypt an id for use as a query parameter in asp.net core.  I have provided info on this as well as working code.  Unfortunately stackoverflow is a question and answer website not a debugging site, code review website or tutorial website.  The amount of code you provided was too voluminous for the typical question but I went ahead and provided an answer to your primary question.  If my answer is not sufficient, I suggest you break up your question into several smaller ones and submit several focused questions.

Comment: @RonC, Ok, I will create another post then. I accepted your answer, as it's somewhat of a stepping stone to what I actually need. I tried to implement what you supplied in code to my existing code and no dice. Also, the link that you mentioned that I was also looking at prior to this post doesn't seem to provide the answer that I need.

Comment: @BrianBrian Apologizes. I did make a mistake when I copied the code from my test controller to StackOverflow.  I have updated the code and added a paragraph of backstory to explain a potential gotcha.  I hope it helps you get it working.

Comment: @RonC, There is no need to apologize. I added that piece that was missing from the initial link that I was looking at which is the same that you supplied as well. However, I'm still at a lose on how to implement with my code. My problem, is that I'm not sure were or what I need to apply that code too. My query for the Index, Edit and Delete actions methods look different than the example.